# Partial menu - Return Data - Laravel

Tags: laravel

in my Laravel project i have many views, and a partial menu in the top for all views. 
When i set a variable in blade i return it inside a specific view with

```
return view ('view',compact('variable'))
```

and i set my root like that :

```
Route::get('/',['uses'=>'Controller@FunctionX']);
```

But what i need now  is to set and return a variable into my partiable menu, so it could be visible for all views.

how can we do that please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the official documentation. You can pass data into all vies using Composer views. What you need to do is go to App\Providers\AppServiceProvider. And just do your query.

```
$data=DB::table('data')->first();
```

And then you need to return

```
View::share('data', $data);
```

And that's all. You can now use {{$data->id}}  in all your views. Don't forget to include

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
```

[LARAVELDOC](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#passing-data-to-views)

Comment: hello sir, isn't working, i wrote 
 public function boot()
    {
    $data=DB::table('coins')->first();
    View::share('coins','$data');
    }

In my view i wrote : {{$coins->id}}

Error message : Undifined variable